# Count order date if it is the first order of the customer

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bc5985bfdb4a4cbfbfd84650d2fa74c5)**

```
/* table sales */
CREATE TABLE sales (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    order_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO sales
(customerID, order_date
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "2020-03-15"),
("Customer_01", "2020-03-20"),
("Customer_02", "2020-06-16"),
("Customer_03", "2020-07-27"),
("Customer_03", "2020-08-05"),
("Customer_04", "2020-08-10"),
("Customer_04", "2021-03-14");


/* table customers */
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    first_order DATE
);

INSERT INTO customers
(customerID, first_order
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "2020-03-15"),
("Customer_02", "2020-06-16"),
("Customer_03", "2020-07-27"),
("Customer_04", "2020-08-10");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
customerID      order_date     first_order    COUNT(distinct s.customerID)
Customer_01     2020-03-15     2020-03-15               1
Customer_01     2020-03-20     2020-03-15               0
Customer_02     2020-06-16     2020-06-16               1
Customer_03     2020-07-27     2020-07-27               1
Customer_03     2020-08-05     2020-07-27               0
Customer_04     2020-08-10     2020-08-10               1
```

---

My `database` consists of two tables `sales` and `customers`. 
In the `customers` table you can finde the date of the `first_order` per customers. 
In the `sales` table you can find each `order` a customer has done so far.

Now, I want to create a list with all `order_dates` and in case the `order_date` was a `first_order` the `COUNT` should be `1`. 
Otherwise the `COUNT` should be `0`.

---

So far, I came to this query:

```
SELECT
s.customerID,
s.order_date,
c.first_order,
COUNT(distinct s.customerID)
FROM sales s
JOIN customers c ON c.customerID = s.customerID
WHERE order_date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
AND first_order BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

Do you have any idea how I have to modify it to get the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `join` and conditional logic. I don’t see why you would need aggregation here:

```
select 
    s.customerID,
    s.order_date,
    c.first_order,
    (s.order_date = c.first_order) is_first_order
from sales s
inner join customers c on c.customerID = s.customerID
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f31f614b4896a045f8ab1853993ccea3

Answer (score 1):

You can use an IF Clause to check the dates

> ```
> SELECT
> s.customerID,
> s.order_date,
> c.first_order,
> IF(s.order_date = c.first_order,1,0 )
> FROM sales s
> JOIN customers c ON c.customerID = s.customerID
> WHERE order_date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
> AND first_order BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> customerID  | order_date | first_order | IF(s.order_date = c.first_order,1,0 )
> :---------- | :--------- | :---------- | ------------------------------------:
> Customer_01 | 2020-03-15 | 2020-03-15  |                                     1
> Customer_01 | 2020-03-20 | 2020-03-15  |                                     0
> Customer_02 | 2020-06-16 | 2020-06-16  |                                     1
> Customer_03 | 2020-07-27 | 2020-07-27  |                                     1
> Customer_03 | 2020-08-05 | 2020-07-27  |                                     0
> Customer_04 | 2020-08-10 | 2020-08-10  |                                     1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6cdb5867502442698a4c79043ec97c14)*

Answer (score 1):

In your query you can sum the times the `order_date` is equal to the `first_order`:

```
SELECT
  s.customerID,
  s.order_date,
  c.first_order,
  SUM(s.order_date = c.first_order) total
FROM sales s JOIN customers c 
ON c.customerID = s.customerID
WHERE order_date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
  AND first_order BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
GROUP BY s.customerID, s.order_date, c.first_order;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f345ce3360fd26b2a7a6574a29aff153).
Results:

```
> customerID  | order_date | first_order | total
> :---------- | :--------- | :---------- | ----:
> Customer_01 | 2020-03-15 | 2020-03-15  |     1
> Customer_01 | 2020-03-20 | 2020-03-15  |     0
> Customer_02 | 2020-06-16 | 2020-06-16  |     1
> Customer_03 | 2020-07-27 | 2020-07-27  |     1
> Customer_03 | 2020-08-05 | 2020-07-27  |     0
> Customer_04 | 2020-08-10 | 2020-08-10  |     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "count" is a little confusing - but this version is another option:

```
SELECT
s.customerID,
s.order_date,
c.first_order,
CASE
  when c.first_order = order_date then 1
  else 0
end 
FROM sales s
JOIN customers c ON c.customerID = s.customerID
WHERE order_date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
AND first_order BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-12-31"
GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```