# Count date if it is in the same months as the first order of the customer

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3fabd2eb65e04347d8211e2354417fdf)**

```
/* table returned */
CREATE TABLE returned (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    returned_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO returned
(customerID, returned_date
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "2020-03-20"),
("Customer_01", "2020-03-22"),
("Customer_01", "2020-04-19"),
("Customer_02", "2020-08-09"),
("Customer_03", "2020-07-31"),
("Customer_03", "2020-08-25"),
("Customer_04", "2020-09-16"),
("Customer_04", "2021-09-25");


/* table customers */
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    customerID VARCHAR(255),
    first_order DATE
);

INSERT INTO customers
(customerID, first_order
)
VALUES 
("Customer_01", "2020-03-15"),
("Customer_02", "2020-06-16"),
("Customer_03", "2020-07-27"),
("Customer_04", "2020-08-10");
```

**Expected Result**

```
customerID      returned_date   first_order             COUNT
Customer_01     2020-03-20      2020-03-15                1
Customer_01     2020-03-22      2020-03-15                0
Customer_01     2020-04-19      2020-03-15                0
Customer_02     2020-08-09      2020-06-16                0
Customer_03     2020-07-31      2020-07-27                1
Customer_03     2020-08-25      2020-07-27                0
Customer_04     2020-09-16      2020-08-10                0
```

---

My database consists of two tables `returned` and `customers`. 
In the `customers` table you can find the date of the `first_order` per customer. 
In the `returned` table you can find each return a customer has done so far.

Now, I want to create a list and `count` all `returned_dates` which are in the **same month** as the `first_order` date of a certain customer. 
If there are multiple orders in the **same month** then only the first match should be counted `1`. 
 The others should be `0`. *(see Customer_01 in the example)*

---

The difference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63448228/count-order-date-if-it-is-the-first-order-of-the-customer) is that there is no `return_date` that matches exactly with a `first_order` date. 
Therefore, this query does not work:

```
SELECT
r.customerID,
r.returned_date,
c.first_order,
(r.returned_date = c.first_order) is_first_order
FROM returned r
INNER JOIN customers c ON c.customerID = r.customerID
```

Do you have any idea how I can achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select r.customerID, r.returned_date, c.first_order,
       (case when r.returned_date < c.first_order + interval 1 month and
                  row_number() over (partition by c.customerID order by returned_date) = 1
             then 1 else 0
         end) as return_flag
from returned r join
     customers c
     on c.customerID = r.customerID;
```

This flags the first return as "1" only if it is the first order and occurs within a month of the start date for the customer.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5d53be571588fac9eea4579832854e2a

Comment: For my own documenation. In my origianl file I came to the right result with this query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2a5359dca713311f5161562a9abab914

Comment: @Michi . . . Only comparing the calendar month is quite dangerous.  If what you intend is the calendar month (which is quite biased against customers who start at the end of the month), then be sure you include the year as well.